# MapView not working on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, tablet

Apparently my Android app isn't working as it should on Samsung Galaxy Tab. The MapView don't display map/satellite tiles on the Tab. On other devices the MapView works as it should. I don't own a Tab myself so I have problem finding out what might be wrong and I have no clue right now what might cause it. Any point in the right direction is highly appreciated.

The app works in emulator using the avd distribued by Samsung in the emulator with the fix described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg123342.html) in order to be able to debug MapView in it.

Info from AndroidManifest.xml that might be interesting:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" 
/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application android:name=".MyAppName"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false"
>
    <activity android:name=".InitialActivity">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <activity android:name=".FavoriteSpotActivity" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Comment: Would you please repost the entire AndroidManifest what you've posted is kinda messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one myself. Using r06 of Android SDK the Google API key was refused when trying to create the MapView. Recompiling it with r07 of Android SDK solved the issue though. Good to know if someone run into the same problem as I did.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you did this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the tablet is missing Google APIs - com.google.android.maps library

Comment: I think the avd Samsung sends out is missing it but not in the device itself, right?